# Langchain and openai chat bot

Tags: python-3.x, openai-api, langchain

lately I have been trying to use langchain in order to create a chat bot that gives answers based only on the given context. For some reason, I cannot find a parameter that takes in my consideration only my data. Sometimes it will give answers from somewhere else.

```
conversation = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
                llm=ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0),
                retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 1}),
                memory=self.memory
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with explicitly specifying in prompt

```
# Create conversational chain 
chain = ConversationalChain(
llm=chat_model, 
retriever=vectorstore.retriever(k=1),
combine_docs_chain_kwargs={'prompt': 'You are an AI assistant who answers questions. You only know what is contained in the provided documents. Do not use any outside knowledge'}
)
```

Comment: I am getting this error: prompt
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)

Comment: updated the code, it was missing ' } '

Comment: I have already tried that too, still the same error